# I installed the packege google_fonts in my flutter app and now i get this error

Tags: android, flutter

i wanted to change the fonts of my flutter app and i installed the google fonts package and now, everytime i want to open my app, i get this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Go in debug mode...
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings
ERROR:E:\Documents\p\next\f\Flutter_test\notes\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform classes.jar (project :path_provider_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: E:\Documents\p\next\f\Flutter_test\notes\build\path_provider_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Exited (1).
```

before i installed the package, it worked quite good

i tried putting this in my build.gradle file but i didn't work, it's still the same

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' 
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flutter clean > flutter pub get > run

still facing issues, try below:

Create a new Flutter project and paste the existing asset, library, and other necessary folders. Now add the google_fonts package to pubspec.yaml,

dependencies:

```
google_fonts: <latest_version>
```

import google fonts:

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
```

Now you can change the entire app's font family using the below:

```
MaterialApp( theme:ThemeData(textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme()));
```

or change a specific text style

```
Text( 
        'Hello World!', 
        style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic), 
      ),
```

Comment: it's Still the same @Veeramanikandan R Developer -